# Is there a way to pass parameters back from a Blazor component in a BlazorWebView to the code behind of XAML page in .NET MAUI (aka EventCallBack?)

Tags: c#, xaml, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have a ContentPage in a MAUI Blazor Hybrid app with a BlazorWebView (BWV) that displays a basic form component. I understand how to pass parameters to the RootComponent of the BWV so that the Blazor component has access to the info, but I can't figure out how to do the reverse and pass a response from the component to the .xaml.cs code behind file. Essentially I want to do an EventCallBack like a child component would pass info to its parent component in Blazor. I can't seem to find any info about this so any help would be appreciated!

I tried creating an EventCallBack in the Blazor component and binding that to the BWV in the XAML but I can't seem to find the proper way to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question and also create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear, but I am gonna assume you are trying to share data/information between your blazor page and your maui page. For this I would use dependency injection and a state container to store and share the data.

Create a class and add it via dependency injection. (You can also use an interface). The snippet below might help.

Create your class to hold your data: MySessionValues.cs

```
public class MySessionValues
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginTime { get; set; }
}
```

Register the class for dependency injection: MauiProgram.cs

```
    //Register dependency injection for Maui pages bellow:
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<App>();
    //To be used by Maui and Blazor pages
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<MySessionValues>();
```

Now in yout blazor page, Inject the MySessionValues Class: MyBlazorPage1.razor

```
@inject MySessionValues _mySessionValues;
//get your values from your state class like so.
<label @bind="_mySessionvalues.FirstName" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SetMyValues">Set My Values</button>

private async void SetMyValues()
    {
//you can set your values however you want. Typically from an api call
        _mySessionvalues.FirstName = "Dave";
        _mySessionvalues.Amount = "5000.98";
        _mySessionvalues.LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now;
        _mySessionvalues.Id = "12345";
    }
```

Your state stays the same across pages cos it’s a singleton.
On the Maui pages side, dependency injection is started from the root app. So in your app.xaml.cs file, inject your state class into the constructor like so.

```
public App(MySessionValues _mySessionValues)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

Then whenever you want to use MySessionValues in any Maui page, simply inject it into the constructor of that page like so: TestMauiPage.xaml.cs

```
public TestMauiPage(MySessionValues _mySessionValues)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mylabel.Text = _mySessionValues.FirstName;
    }
```

In you TestMauiPage.xaml: just name the default label so you can reference it from code, or you can use binding. And you should see your values.

```
 <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            x:Name="mylabel"
            TextColor="Black"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Remember whenever you are calling the Maui page, you have to pass it a MySessionValues as the constructor is no longer parameterless.
Eg.

```
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyMauiPages.TestMauiPage(_mySessionvalues));
```

Note: in your app.xaml.cs file, it also a good idea to inject _mySessionValues into MainPage, so your state is available to your root maui page(s).

```
public App(MySessionValues _mySessionValues)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage(_mySessionValues);
    }
```

Should you need to display Maui page and Razor Page side by side and have data exchange in real time, then you will need to subscribe to a Notification event in your class.